# Refer to a column where the letter part is in another cell

Tags: excel

I want to use `MODE` to find the most common value in a column. Thing is though that the column changes. Therefore I have a sheet called Preferences where there's a cell `F5` where you specify the letter of the column.

Right now the cell contains the letter R. I then want the formula to be `=MODE(R:R)`

I've tried `=MODE(INDIRECT(Preferences!F5):INDIRECT(Preferences!F5))` but it's not working.

How do I enter this formula correctly?

Comment: Thank you! :) But what do you mean it's volatile, is there a better way?

Comment: Just noticed that Excel started so work really slow. Like really, really slow. Tried a lot of things. Eventually I removed the formula and suddenly it sped up to normal speed. It seems it didn't work that well after all! Are there other options to do this?

Comment: Ah, you dived into volatile functions a bit too deep there then. I posted a workaround using `INDEX`, a semi-volatile functions that would only recalculate on start-up.

Comment: Sorry, can't remember if it worked, not sure if I even tried it. I came up with a totally different method which I use now, where I code it in VBA. So sorry!